# lxml.objectify.parse fails while fromstring works

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, lxml.objectify

Struggling on why lxml.objectify.parse is failing when I use a file IO but not a string IO.

The following code works:

```
with open(logPath,'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    xml = f.read()
    root = objectify.fromstring(xml)

print(root.tag)
```

The following code fails with error:

> AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._ElementTree' object has no attribute 'tag'

```
with open(pelogPath,'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    #xml = f.read()
    root = objectify.parse(f)

print(root.tag)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because [`fromstring()`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#fromstring) would return a root element directly:

> Parses an XML document or fragment from a string. Returns the root node (or the result returned by a parser target).

while the [`parse()`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#parse) would return an `ElementTree` object:

> Return an ElementTree object loaded with source elements.

Use `getroot()` to get to the root element in this case:

```
tree = objectify.parse(f)
root = tree.getroot()
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't see this in any of the doc... this fixed it.